# print up to or from nth key OrderedDict() python

Tags: python, ordereddictionary

How can i print the first 10 or last 10 key, value pairs of an OrderedDict in python?

this

```
for item in my_ordereddict[:5]:
    print item
```

or this:

```
for i in range(0, 5):
    print my_ordereddict[i]
```

dont work.
Any help?

Comment: @SandipanDey I don't think it's a dupe, an `OrderedDict` specifically does away with the "no order" restriction.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  "dont work" [sic] is not a problem specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from collections import OrderedDict


if __name__ == '__main__':
    od = OrderedDict([["one", 1], ["two", 2], ["three", 3], ["four", 4], ["five", 5], ["six", 6]])
    for i in od.keys()[0:3]:
        print od[i]
```

Comment: This fails in Python 3 as the various DictViews are not subscriptable.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `itertools.islice` to slice the `OrderedDict.items()` view

```
from itertools import islice
from collections import OrderedDict

o = OrderedDict()
for i in range(100):
    o[i] = 2*i

for i in islice(o.items(), 0, 10):
    print(i)
```

Outputs:

```
(0, 0)
(1, 2)
(2, 4)
(3, 6)
(4, 8)
(5, 10)
(6, 12)
(7, 14)
(8, 16)
(9, 18)
```